# How to not store __key__ in datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Here is how i am persisting data to datastore

```
type UserDetails struct {
    UserID    string `datastore:"__key__"`
    Name      string
    UserEmail string
}

func (c DataStoreClient) Put(ctx context.Context, orgID string, ud *UserDetails) (id int64, err error) {
    key := datastore.NameKey(userKind, ud.UserID, nil)
    key.Namespace = orgID

    k, err := c.client.Put(ctx, key, ud)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return k.ID, nil
}

func (ud *DataStoreUserDetails) Save() ([]datastore.Property, error) {
    return datastore.SaveStruct(ud)
}

func (ud *DataStoreUserDetails) LoadKey(k *datastore.Key) error {
    ud.UserID = k.Name
    return nil
}

func (ud *DataStoreUserDetails) Load(ps []datastore.Property) error {
    return datastore.LoadStruct(ud, ps)
}
```

When i call `Put` method, i am able to store `UserDetails` successfully in datastore. But, along with all the columns in `UserDetails`, I can also see `__key__` column. I don't want that. I want to keep `UserID` as the key for this table.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the datastore name "-" to ignore the field when saving or loading the entity.

```
type UserDetails struct {
    UserID    string `datastore:"-"` // <-- change on this line
    Name      string
    UserEmail string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following, "**key**" has to be a *datastore.Key type but you are using string type. Don't know if that has an effect.

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-Key_Field

But for what you are trying to achieve, you can do either of two things. Change UserID to "userID" and not specify a tag or use

UserID string `datastore:"-"`

This will prevent it from being stored.